# How to get a facebook user id if he is not logged into your app?

Tags: php, facebook

I want the get a users facebook ID, but that user is not registered to my app.

I only want his ID to have a picture of him, but Can I even have his ID if he is not inside my app? 
** the user is logged into facebook.

Thank you.

I'm using facebook php API.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't think so....................................

Try logging out of facebook (you), then visiting a user's profile. What do you see? Well that's all the information you can have without them "connecting" to your app.

Perhaps you can have your script check for their facebook cookie... good luck with that.

Comment: I can get their photo and ID without logging into facebook...
Well never mind, Ill do somthing else.

Comment: Your only bet is to find out what their profile ID is by looking at the cookies on their system. Can you even do that??? I don't know!

Comment: well if you have his username, yes you can get an ID and a picture. http://graph.facebook.com/<username> it contains the ID and http://graph.facebook.com/<ID>/picture is the profile pic

Comment: How do you figure out what the user's username is? Can you dig through their cookies and find out? I've never actually tried something like that before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to get information from facebook of someone that you don't know who they are.  You would need a data match of some sort to accomplish this, and most of all, consent.  This is primarily done for security purposes, otherwise you could get any information from anyone with nothing but a reference to their name, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

There is an  "`fbs_[appid]`" cookie. You will get everything required in that cookie.

Comment: So i'm guessing one is allowed to view cookies from any website using code on their own website???